# python scripts in cgi-bin stopped working

Tags: python, web-hosting, cgi-bin

I have been playing around with python and decided to start testing out putting some of the scripts on the web.

I have a domain registered and hosted with hostpresto.com and managed to get my scripts up and running last night.

That is creating a html form in public_html which runs a .py script in cgi-bin to return a temperature conversion. (jvmaguire.com/form.html)

This was working and so I set up a few other scripts. However, I have woken up this morning to find that the cgi-bin scripts are returning a 404 error now.

Does anyone have any idea what may have happened overnight?

One of my scripts was running a query on the skypicker api and a few of my friends were using it overnight, but I can't imagine that would affect anything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is best asked to your hosting provider - at the very least, to get the cause of the `404` errors.

Comment: So my host for back to me on this. They said they "reset" the cgi permissions and that they weren't enabled on my account. I'm just putting it down to teething problems as it's a new service etc